# How to remove data type name from print result

Tags: php, snmp

I need to remove the data type text ("STRING:" and "INTEGER:" below) from my output result.

This is the code:

```
$session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2c, "host", "community");
$interface= $session->get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.32610");
$snr= $session->get(".1.3.6.1.2.1.10.127.1.1.4.1.5.32610");
echo "$interface\n";
echo "$snr\n";
```

Result:

```
STRING: Cable5/0/0-upstream1
INTEGER: 354
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$session = new SNMP(SNMP::VERSION_2c, "host", "community");
$session->quick_print = 1; // print just the value, no types
$session->valueretrieval = SNMP_VALUE_PLAIN; // no quotes for strings
//...code
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.snmp.php#snmp.props